# coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, UserProfile found

Tags: python, admin, django-1.7

When i try to view FileShare in my admin panel in Django1.7 i get this error

```
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, UserProfile found
```

My models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,primary_key=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
    User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])

class FileDetails(models.Model):
    fileId = models.CharField(max_length = 100,primary_key=True,db_index=True)        
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.fileId

class Permission(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user

class FileShare(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    file_requested=models.ForeignKey(FileDetails)
    permission=models.ManyToManyField(Permission)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.owner)
```

Why this error ? How can i correct it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define the `__unicode__` method for Permission, it should be `return str(self.user)` instead of `return self.user`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Permission` object returns a `UserProfile` object when converting to Unicode:

```
class Permission(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user
```

The [`__unicode__` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#unicode) must return a `unicode` object, always, instead. You could use the [`unicode()` type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode) on `self.user` to provide such a value:

```
class Permission(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unucode(self.user)
```

You probably want to do the same in your `FileShare` model:

```
class FileShare(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    file_requested=models.ForeignKey(FileDetails)
    permission=models.ManyToManyField(Permission)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.owner)
```

You are using `str()` there instead, which will result in a string containing *UTF-8 bytes* instead, which will then have to be (implicitly) decoded again. But Python will try to use the ASCII codec for that, and if the owner username contains anything other than ASCII characters that decoding will fail.